# Best client side library for creating webkit (Android IOS) Web App Interfaces

Tags: javascript, android, ios, webkit

What is the best client side library (framework) for creating web-based  applications  (not phone specific appsfor modern smartphones (WEbkit compatible).

I 'm mostly thinking of a modern, light JavaScript framework that is specially designed to work with modern Web-kit enabled smart phones.

I heard http://jquerymobile.com was pretty good any suggestions or comments..

Answer (score 0):

JQuery's is the only big new thing I'm aware of. Also keep in mind, jq-mobile is more of a widget library. You still have to use the JQ core as a dependency. The rash of new smartphones and platforms to deal with has pretty much turned things into the wild west for web UI devs.

Fortunately most modern Android and iPhone browsers are pretty close to their desktop equivalents. I even found as-you-go testing in Windows Phone 7 with IE 8 in IE 7 mode to be a pretty good indicator of what things would look like in a Win Phone emulator but I don't think we should encourage Microsoft by supporting their outdated-at-release mobile garbage browsers before they capture market share, which will hopefully light a fire under their butts to get it right on their next mobile browser.

Since the general practice at the moment seems to be to keep things very simple and we don't really have to branch for IE for a change, the two biggest reasons to use a framework in the first place have been removed, although JQ-core is light enough for modern smart phones, IMO, and it can save some development time if you have a fair amount of behavior to build